# PostgreSQL - Update column in table by reading from other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, insert

I'm trying to update **SKU** column in **product_identifier** table by using same value from **product_stock** table.
I cannot do that directly. First i have to get **variant id** from **product_variant** then find **SKU** from **product_stock** by using variant_id
And finally update SKU column in product_identifier table with variant's SKU

```
product_id = SELECT id FROM product

variant_id = SELECT id FROM product_variant WHERE product_id=product_id

sku = SELECT sku FROM product_stock WHERE variant_id=variant_id

UPDATE product_identifier SET sku='sku'
```

(sorry, i've little SQL knowledge. tried to explain it by assiging it to value)

Summary of code above:

Fetch product ids from PRODUCT table

Find variant ids of the product using product id

Find SKU code of the variant id

Then update SKU value in product_identifier using product id

--
Table Samples

PRODUCT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk1HX.png)

PRODUCT_VARIANT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dIca.png)

PRODUCT_STOCK
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApaVp.png)

--
*PS. One product might have many variants*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `FROM` clause in the `UPDATE` statement.  But you need to figure out how you are matching `product_identifier` to the other tables.  Your question is not clear on that point:

```
UPDATE product_identifier pi
    SET sku = ps.sku
    FROM product p JOIN
         product_variant pv
         ON pv.product_id = p.id JOIN
         product_stock ps
         ON ps.variant_id = pv.id
    WHERE pi.? = ?.?;  -- your join condition goes here
```